# How to check a receive response from server in artillery ws

Tags: yaml, artillery

In my yml file, unable to check the receive response from ws server and how i print that.
Would you please help me to out from this problem. is it available ? to check the receive response from web socket server in artillery.

```
   capture:  
     json: "$.fooBody"
     as: "fooBody"
#- log: "{{statusCode}} => {{ fooBody }}"        
- log: "data: {{ fooBody }}"
```

In above script i used but not works for me.

I want to check the received data from  server and send the same data to server.
after run the artillery file it shows the

- data : undefine